# Java writing/reading unserializable objects to/from file

Tags: java, spatial-index, notserializableexception

I am using [JSI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsi/) (Java Spatial Index, RTree) to implement 2D spatial search. I want to save the tree to file, which triggered `java.io.NotSerializableException` using code below.

```
public class GeographicIndexer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GeographicIndexer.class);  
    public SpatialIndex spatialIndex = null;

    public void init() {
        this.spatialIndex = new RTree();
        this.spatialIndex.init(null);
    }

    public void add(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, int id) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        this.spatialIndex.add(rect, id);
    }

    public void add(float x, float y, int id) {
        this.add(x, y, x, y, id);
    }

    public void saveIndex(String indexStorePath) {
        try {
            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(indexStorePath);
            OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);    
            try {
                output.writeObject(this.spatialIndex);
            } finally {
                output.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            log.error("Fail to write geographic index");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public GeographicIndexer loadIndex(String indexStorePath) {
        try {
            InputStream file = new FileInputStream(indexStorePath);
            InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
            ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);

            try {
                this.spatialIndex = (SpatialIndex)input.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                log.error("Fail to read geographic index");
            } finally {
                input.close();
            }

            return this;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            log.error("Fail to read geographic index");
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I serialize this 3rd party class so that I can read/write it?
Thanks.

Comment: Probably the class doesn't implement `Serializable` !

Comment: can you catch the exception after `output.writeObject(this.spatialIndex);` and print the full trace? Looks like `try` is followed by 'finally'

Comment: @noob It doesn't. Does it means I cannot save it to file?

Comment: @sanbhat Like this: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.infomatiq.jsi.rtree.RTree

Comment: @Rodolphe : No , But I think you can write it to something like an XML and read that XMl back to construct the state

Comment: @noob: Thanks a lot! I am thinking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `com.infomatiq.jsi.rtree.RTree` doesn't implement `Serializable` you cannot use Java Serialization to persist the state of its object . You can use other frameworks for Serialization , like the  [one here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)  .

Answer (score 1):

Since RTree does not implement Serializable you cannot use Java Serialization for it.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please recommend some way to implement writing/reading such object?

Answer (score -1):

Try to extend it, Make the extended class serializable. Then you should be able to write to file.

Comment: Merely making a class extend a Superclass doesnt help serialize the super-class. We need to copy all the variables in the child class and then serialize.